# Controlling for collinearity with one variable to test effects of second variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity

Here's my situation:

Response variable: 0/1 Alive/Dead Bernoulli data
Predictor 1: Categorical (Brand of drug)
Predictor 2: Continuous (Dose of drug)

I want to run a logistic regression to test whether there's an effect of Predictor 1 on the response.  However, I wasn't able to control the dose of the drugs that were ingested. I do, however, know how much was ingested after the fact. How can I control for Predictor 2 to test the effects of Predictor 1?

My first guess was simply to test for an interaction between the two; if the interaction is insignificant, then the effects of Predictor 1 on the Response must be the same at all "levels" of Predictor 2.

Is that inherently wrong? Is there a better way to skin this cat?

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need an interaction. Simply including both predictors does control for the effect of dose on drug under the assumption that their effects are additive. Testing the interaction, as you propose, is also a good idea.

However, there is no reason to believe that either the additive or the interaction effect is correct. If your situation is one where all the brands are identical drugs, I would suggest using a spline for the dose variable, and including the interaction as well if it is significant (although interpretation can be a bit ugly, so you need to be careful to compute something like an average effect for each brand, rather than just rely on the coefficients). The `mgcv` package in R has always been my go to for such models.

However, if the brands have different drugs in them, it gets more complex. 
Consider the situation where the drugs are analgesics. The recommended dose of a paracetamol in mg would generally be higher than that of an aspirin. So, a better variable than dose here may be dose / recommended dose.

Similarly, it could be that different drugs have threshold effects (e.g., perhaps one drug is particularly poor at lower doses, or, beyond a certain point, a higher dose as no effect), in which case you may want to transform the data to reflect the expected effect of the dose, rather than the actual dose.

Typically, there is no obviously-correct answer to these questions, so the solution is to come up with a series of plausible models and check that the effect you are testing for exists in all of the plausible models (i.e., conduct a sensitivity analysis).

Comment: Could you expand on your second paragraph and the use of a spline for a variable, or perhaps direct me somewhere that would be useful? I simplified my description of the predictor variables a bit, but essentially the drugs are all the same compound with the same recommended dose for each.

I appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Using the spline means you are not assuming a linear relationship between the dose and the outcome (think of a spline as being a bit like a higher order polynomial, but better). This is relevant because if there is an association between the dose and the brand effects, and, a non-linear relationship between dose and the outcome, assuming a linear effect for dose is going to cause the brand effects to be wrong.